# How to read data from a sector using NFC on Android

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare

I am trying to read the data from an NFC card I have for a project. It is using Mifare classic 1k and has 16 sectors.

I am able to connect to the card and I'm trying to read the data (I know the data that I want is in the 2nd sector - 2nd Block). I can scan the card fine and it shows me the size of the card so this ensures me that the card is being scanned properly but the data I get when I Log the "data.readBlock(2)" is just the same as the key I use to authenticate it.

What I understand from the code:
Card connects
Auth == true
I can get overall details of the card such as sector count / block count

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
            super.onNewIntent(intent);
            Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            MifareClassic tag = MifareClassic.get(tagFromIntent) ;
            try {
                //Variables
                int sectorCount = tag.getSectorCount();
                int tagSize = tag.getSize();
                boolean auth;
                //Keys
                byte[] defaultKeys = new byte[]{};
                defaultKeys = MifareClassic.KEY_DEFAULT;
                //Connecting to tag
                tag.connect();
                //auth = true
                auth = tag.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(2, defaultKeys);
                byte[] data = tag.readBlock(2);
                Log.i("OnNewIntent", "Data in sector 2: " + Arrays.toString(data));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Expected = "Data in sector 2: `The data in sector 2 block 2`"

Actual = "Data in sector 2: [B@4df9e32"

The above Actual result changes each time the card is scanned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are getting is the object reference Java uses to keep it in memory. To get a readable version of the data instead use:

```
Arrays.toString(data);
```

By the way, you may want to change your code to check if the authentication was successful:

```
authSuccessful = mfc.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(sector, key);

if(authSuccessful){
    // Read the block
    creditBlock = mfc.readBlock(block);

    String bytesString = Arrays.toString(creditBlock);
    Log.i(TAG, bytesString);

} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "Auth Failed");
}
```

Finally, I'm pretty sure what you are trying to do is just the standard Mifare card read so avoid jumping to conclusions. As they say in medicine:

> Think horses, not zebras

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for the response. I have tried this and it returned a "[4]" which i'm assuming is the size of the block. You can probably tell that i'm very new to NFC so do you have any other suggestions as to how this might print the data in the block? Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to read block 2 which is located in sector 0, by authenticating to sector 2. Blocks numbering does not restart every sector. So if you want to read block 2 of sector 2 the block number should be 9. Remember block count as well as sector count both start at 0.

Comment: Personally, [this tutorial](https://mifareclassicdetectiononandroid.blogspot.com/2011/04/reading-mifare-classic-1k-from-android.html) is what I used to start on the topic.

Comment: I've checked out the link and i've got something to work from it... It's all numbers though, not actual strings which i know are on the card. Very confusing, any ideas what the numbers are? for example, this is what i get as an output to the code above if i change the sector to 9: [83, 88, 48, 48, 49, 51, 54, 55, 48, 56, 32, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35]

Comment: If your original problem has been solved, please click on the checkmark next to my answer. What you are seeing right now are the bytes stored on the card, which is absolutely what you are supposed to get. I recommend getting a better grasp of what you are dealing with before continuing. You will need to process these bytes into what you need and to do that you need to know how the information is being stored in the card.

Comment: May I suggest getting the app 'MIFARE Classic Tool' available on the play store so you can see the internal structure of your card and possibly get a better idea?

Comment: I went ahead and processed your bytes through an [HEX to ASCII converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html) and got the string 'QTUHV255555'. Is this what you are supposed to get?

Comment: Afraid not, that's where the information is but it's not the right string

Comment: Only if you can tell us more about your particular case will we be able to help you

Comment: I am trying to read an ID that is on the card that was in sector 2 and block 2 of that sector in another application I used to view it. I want to scan the card and retrieve that unique ID so I can do more processing with it. What else would you like to know?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem eventually by converting the memory location to a string and then converting that string to a UTF-8 format. Cheers for the help